# Can’t edit Sticky Header Opacity

Tags: css, wordpress, header, opacity, sticky

I got this code from the web to add sticky header to my wordpress website but I want to make the opacity 100% and when I edit it in the code it doesn’t take any effect on live site the far I can go is 0.99.
I just don’t want any transparency at all, that’s why I set Opacity to “1.0” in the code but it doesn’t render in the site.
URL: https://ozaro.com

```
header.sticky-header {
    --header-height: 90px;
    --opacity: 1.0;
    --shrink-me: 0.80;
    --sticky-background-color: #00000;
    --transition: .3s ease-in-out;

    transition: background-color var(--transition),
                background-image var(--transition),
                backdrop-filter var(--transition),
                opacity var(--transition);
}
header.sticky-header.elementor-sticky--effects {
    background-color: var(--sticky-background-color) !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    opacity: var(--opacity) !important;
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(99999px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(99999px);
}
header.sticky-header > .elementor-container {
    transition: min-height var(--transition);
}
header.sticky-header.elementor-sticky--effects > .elementor-container {
    min-height: calc(var(--header-height) * var(--shrink-me))!important;
    height: calc(var(--header-height) * var(--shrink-me));
}
header.sticky-header .elementor-nav-menu .elementor-item {
    transition: padding var(--transition);
}
header.sticky-header.elementor-sticky--effects .elementor-nav-menu .elementor-item {
    padding-bottom: 10px!important;
    padding-top: 10px!important;
}
header.sticky-header > .elementor-container .logo img {
    transition: max-width var(--transition);
}
header.sticky-header.elementor-sticky--effects .logo img {
    max-width: calc(100% * var(--shrink-me));
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please provide a minimal reproducible code snippet to show the issue you getting. CSS line with the corrsponding HTMl structure is nearly always sueless to us. Only if we get full informations we will be able to help.

Comment: In my device also displays 0.99. So it looks like you are doing something wrong with loading your css. In wordpress you cant load them like regular css files in html. You are working on your own custom template or you are just working on theme from wordpress dashboard ?

Comment: You should look through your theme settings... ...it looks as though it allows you to assign theme colours from a pre-set list and some of those colours are RGBA.  The A in RGBA is the Alpha channel, that controls opacity.  So you could set the opacity of the header to 1.0 (or 100%) but if the background colour is `rgba(0,0,0,0.9)` then the colour itself is only 90% opaque.  I don't think your issue here is the opacity as much as it is the colour.

Comment: @Bartek Ostrowski I am working on elementor and i followed their tutorial to add a sticky header to my site. and i added the custom sticky header code in the "Header" section custom CSS.

Comment: @Tony Djukic Please can you elaborate more? I am really a novoice in html,css and I just followed a tutorial in Elementor site. I now understand that the "A" in "RGBA" controls the opacity but how can I find the corresponding color in my theme or inside elementor? I already have a pre-set colors in my theme "Dark" mode but I set all of them via the theme dashboard not in the CSS files directly.

Comment: I'm not trying to be dismissive but your best bet is to ask for support from the Theme Developer or Elementor.  I haven't the faintest clue where these values could be.  What I do see is that when I look at your source code in Dev tools I see a lot of colours set for the background that look like this: `rgba(201,180,59,0.7)`.  You also have a header, within a header... so try targeting this in your CSS as well: `header.top_panel.top_panel_custom.top_panel_custom_1112.top_panel_custom_split-menu.without_bg_image.scheme_dark`